# Boolean Algebra - Function Simplification/Minimalization

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need help simplifying these boolean algebra functions:

```
X = !A!BC + A!B!C + !ABC + !AB!C + A!BC

Y = (A!D + !AC)(!B(C + BD))

Z = (!A!C + AD)(B(D + !BC))
```

The furthest I got with simplifying each equation is:

```
X = A!B + !AC + !AB!C

Y = A!BC!D + !A!BC

Z = !AB!CD + ABD
```

If someone could explain how they simplified these functions with steps, that would be appreciated.